# Rule to redirect non logged in User to Custom Registration/login Page in .htaccess file

Tags: users, redirect, htaccess, apache

I am trying to redirect not logged in users from the `"/purchaseads/purchase.php"` to custom registration/login url `"/purchaseads/registrationurl"`on wordpress website. Unfortunately when visit the url `"/purchaseads/purchase.php"` even as a non logged on user nothing changes, doesn't redirect to custom register/login form.

The .httaccess snippet i am using is as follows

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?/?)purchase.php 
RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP_HOST}%1/registrationurl [L,QSA]
```

I am checking if this cookie is set `"wordpress_logged_in"` if not redirect to custom register/login url. Not sure if this approach is secure enough. Maybe there are better ways to validate. What could be missing?

Comment: Why do you want to do this with `.htaccess`? Why not with a WP hook? Any specific reasons?

Comment: Does `/purchaseads/purchase.php` exist as a physical file? Where are you placing these directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @MrWhite Good question, these directories are in the .htaccess file which can be found in the same place as the index.php file for wordpress, i.e. /WP_root . Yes, purchase.php exists as a physical file but not in the same directory, this one is linked to a purchase plugin and found here  /WP_root/wp-content/plugins/

Comment: "the same place as the index.php file for wordpress, i.e. /WP_root" - I assume `/WP_root` must be the document root? (Otherwise, the directives I posted in my answer  would not be working  - but they appear to be.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC] 
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?/?)purchase.php 
> RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP_HOST}%1/registrationurl [L,QSA]
> ```

This will result in a 302 (temporary) redirect to `/purchaseads//registrationurl` - note the double-slash. This double-slash is passed through to the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable that WordPress uses to route the URL. So, this may result in WP not being able to route the request.

You would need to remove the optional slash delimiter from the captured subpattern. ie. Change `^(.*?/?)purchase.php` to `^(.*?)/?purchase\.php$` (not forgetting to backslash-escape literal dots).

The second *condition* that checks the URL-path is not required - this check should be performed in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !wordpress_logged_in
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?purchase\.php$  /$1/registrationurl [R=302,L]
```

Your original directive would have *implicitly* triggered a 302 redirect (because you included an absolute URL in the *substitution* string), however, you should be explicit and include the `R` flag. (You *need* to include the `R` flag when the target URL is expressed as root-relative.)

The `QSA` flag is not required here. Nor is the `NC` flag on the preceding *condition*. `!wordpress_logged_in` is the same as `!.*wordpress_logged_in.*$`.

These directives should also go near the top of your `.htaccess` file, to ensure there are no conflicts.

> Not sure if this approach is secure enough.

Whether this is "secure enough" is dependent on the consequences.

What happens if this redirect does not occur? Would any information be exposed or critical action occur?

Simply checking that the string `wordpress_logged_in` does not occur *anywhere* (not just a cookie whose name contains "wordpress_logged_in") in the `Cookie` header does not reliably check that the user is not logged in. It would be relatively trivial for a malicious user to construct a request that bypassed this check.

You can't reliably determine that a user is logged in using `.htaccess`.

Comment: i just tested your directives and it works as expected. How do i redirect user properly back to the intended url i.e. "/purchaseads/purchase.php" after login is successful. tnx

Comment: You can presumably calculate the return URL from the current URL, since the URL-path is the same. (?)

Comment: works as expected after adding the return rule